# Something in Java that is (similar to) parameters

Tags: java, parameters

In Windows you can start .exe files with certain parameters to do certain tasks like:

```
shutdown.exe -s
```

Is there anything like this in Java, I know that I can make a terminal input with a Scanner function, but what if I want to start the application invisible/not from at terminal but still be able to tell the application something.

Comment: The `main()` method in Java has a `String[]` argument that gives you this.

Comment: Can you specify this a little more, how will I be able to do this for real and start the application with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this Program:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
java Example foo bar baz
```

Output will be

```
foo
bar
baz
```

You can also setup the command line arguments passed to the program in Eclipse under <kbd>Run</kbd> > <kbd>Run Configurations</kbd> > <kbd>Arguments</kbd>

Comment: I chose this because it was the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [args4j](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/05/parsing_command.html).

All Java programs allow for command-line inputs through the main method:

```
public void main(String[] args)
```

But args4j allows you to easily create a class and parse flags `something.exe -f flag1`:

```
public class MyOptions {

    @Option(name="-r",usage="recursively run something")
    private boolean recursive;

    @Option(name="-o",usage="output to this file")
    private File out;

    @Option(name="-str")        // no usage
    private String str = "(default value)";

    @Option(name="-n",usage="usage can have new lines in it\n and also it can be long")
    private int num;

    // receives other command line parameters than options
    @Argument
    private List arguments = new ArrayList();
}
```

And you just have to call this class from your main method:

```
public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    MyOptions bean = new MyOptions()
    CmdLineParser parser = new CmdLineParser(bean);
    parser.parseArgument(args);
    // ...
}
```